# Pre commit Hook to append date in committing files

Tags: svn

Is there any provision to append date or author name inside the committing files using pre-commit hook scripts?....thanks in advance for ur help

Answer (score 2):

No need for a pre-commit hook to do that. Keyword substitution is what you need. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html.

I personally hate to have all those information in source files. They just clutter up the files, and are usually not useful. The history is kept in SVN anyway, and having SVN tell that the author of the file is the one who last modified it (and perhaps only fixed a typo) is meaningless, IMHO.